# Redirection to div element php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hi I want that the user becomes redirected to the `main div` after the login. Now the problem is that it wont work. The PHP mysql connection work well but the user wont become redirected to the `main div`. How can the user redirected after successful login to the `main div`?

the error message in my browser:

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

login.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['username'])){
    $cookie = $_COOKIE['username'];
    header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/local/mainn.php');
}
else{
    $message = array();
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        if (
            empty($_POST['f']['username'])

            ) {
                $message['error'] = 'Es wurden nicht alle Felder ausgefüllt.';
            } 
            $mysqli = @new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', '');
                if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
                    $message['error'] = 'Datenbankverbindung fehlgeschlagen: ' . $mysqli->connect_error;
                }
                $query = sprintf(
                    "INSERT INTO user (username)
                    SELECT * FROM (SELECT '%s') as new_user
                    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                        SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = '%s'
                    ) LIMIT 1;",
                    $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['f']['username']),

                    $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['f']['username'])

                );


                $mysqli->query($query);
                if ($mysqli->affected_rows == 1) {
                    $message['success'] = 'Neuer Benutzer (' . htmlspecialchars($_POST['f']['username']) . ') wurde angelegt, <a href="login.php">weiter zur Anmeldung</a>.';
                    header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/local/mainn.php');
                    $id = $mysqli->insert_id;
                } else {

                }
                $t = time() + 60 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000;
                setcookie("username", $_POST['f']['username'], $t);
                setcookie("userid", $id , $t);
                // cookie setzen
                $mysqli->close();
            }
    }
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
        <title>
            HTML Document Structure
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Einstellungen zur Defintion als WebApp -->
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="wrapper1" name="wrapper1">

        <form name="login-form" class="login-form" action="./login.php" method="post">

            <div class="header1">
            </div>

            <div class="content1">
            <label for="username"></label>
            <input name="f[username]" type="text" class="input username" placeholder="Username" id="username"
            />

            </div>

            <div class="footer">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="button" data-theme="b"/>
            </div>

        </form>

    </div>
    <div class="gradient"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    if(navigator.geolocation) {

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                                        success_handler, 
                                        error_handler, 
                                        {enableHighAccuracy:true});

        function success_handler(position) {
            /* Get the location data */
            latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;

            document.cookie = 'latitude='+latitude+'; ';  
    document.cookie = 'longitude='+longitude+'; ';


        }

        function error_handler() {
        output.innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your location";
      };

    }





    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

mainn.php:

```
<body> 
<?php
include("login.php");
?>

<!-- main Seite -->
<div data-role="page" id="main">
<?php
include("usercoords.php");
?>

<div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false"> 

        <h1>localy</h1>
        <a href="#popupLogin" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">range</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupLogin" data-theme="b" class="ui-corner-all">
    <form name="login-form" class="login-form" action="./range.php" method="post" style="padding:10px 20px;">
        <div class="content">
        <label for="slider-fill">Select range:</label>
<input type="range" name="slider-fill" id="slider-fill" value="5" min="0" max="100" step="1" data-highlight="true">
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="create" class="button" data-theme="b"/>

        </div>  
    </form>
</div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">

    </div><!-- div content -->


    <div data-role="footer" data-id="footernav" data-tap-toggle="false" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="navbar" data-theme="b">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#own posts" data-icon="menue" data-transition="fade">own posts</a></li>                
                <li><a href="#main" data-icon="anfahrt" data-transition="fade" class="ui-btn-active">main</a></li>
                <li><a href="#create post" data-icon="kontakt" data-transition="fade">create post</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->       
    </div><!-- /footer -->            
</div><!-- /page -->
```

Comment: Have you thought about using hashtag method to detect the `div id` as a page? - Also the "`ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`" is from you looping and looping the link - So it looks like your continuously calling the redirect

Comment: Ok, but how can I solve the looping?

Comment: So you're trying to make a login functionality, so when they login. It goes to a certain page?

Comment: Yes when the login was successful, or there are cookies and the user had one time made a login which you can see above in login.php ;)

Comment: It's looping because you have `if (isset($_COOKIE['username'])) { header('Location: main.php') }` ... And that is included in the top of main.php.

Comment: Well thanks, but how can I solve this? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted

```
<?php
include("login.php");
?>
```

and launch the application with login.php.